# Does exit(0) pose any issues in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to immediately exit my MFC app in C++. Is exit(0) the best solution? eg. does it prevent destructors from being called, is it threadsafe? etc. Is there a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Windows cleans up the shrapnel.  Not half-written files of course.  A better solution is to not need this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `exit(0)` is the best solution.  It will cause the destructors of global objects (and `static` objects within functions) to run, however it will not cause destructors of stack-allocated or heap-allocated objects to run:

```
// At global scope
ClassWithDestruct globalObject;

void SomeFunction()
{
    static ClassWithDestructor staticObject;
    ClassWithDestructor stackObject;
    ClassWithDestructor *heapObject = new ClassWithDestructor;

    // On the following call to exit(), the destructors of 'globalObject' and
    // 'staticObject' will run, but those of 'stackObject' and 'heapObject' will
    // NOT run
    exit(0);
}
```

As to whether or not it's thread-safe, that's a hard question to answer: you should not be calling `exit` simultaneously from multiple threads, you should only call it once.  If any destructors run as a result of `exit`, or any if any functions registered with [`atexit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) run, then obviously those functions should be thread-safe if they deal with data that could potentially be being used by other threads.

If your program is exiting normally (say, as a result of the user requesting an exit), you should either call `exit` or return from `main`/`WinMain`, which is equivalent to calling `exit`.  If your program is exiting **abnormally** (say, as a result of an access violation or failed assertion), you should call either `_exit` or `abort`, which **do not** call any destructors.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exit *immediately*, ensuring against running *any* destructors and such beforehand, then you probably want to call `abort()`. If you *do* want destructors to execute, then you probably want to use `PostQuitMessage(0);`. Either way, `exit()` is probably the wrong choice.

Answer (score 1):

when a win32 process exits any resource associated with it is cleaned up by the OS, so in order to me it is perfectly ok.

Answer (score 0):

exit(0) exits the process. All memory is cleaned up. On the other hand explicitly managed resources may not be closed. Of course file handles would be closed and stuff in windows buffers will be flushed. However stuff that the application manages will not.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a safe way to end your program. Static-storage data and non-local automatic objects will destruct, but local automatic objects will not.

From 18.3/8 in the C++ standard:

> The function `exit()` has additional
>   behavior in this International
>   Standard:
>
> - First, objects with static storage
>     duration are destroyed and functions
>     registered by calling atexit are
>     called. Non-local objects with static
>     storage duration are destroyed […].
>     (Automatic objects are not destroyed
>     as a result of calling
>     `exit()`.)[207]) […] A local static
>     object `obj3` is destroyed at the same
>     time it would be if a function calling
>     the `obj3` destructor were registered
>     with `atexit` at the completion of the
>     `obj3` constructor.
> - Next, all open C streams (as
>     mediated by the function signatures
>     declared in `<cstdio>`) with unwritten
>     buffered data are flushed, all open C
>     streams are closed, and all files
>     created by calling `tmpfile()` are
>     removed.[209])
>
> [207]: Objects with automatic storage
>   duration are all destroyed in a
>   program whose function `main()`
>   contains no automatic objects and
>   executes the call to `exit()`. Control
>   can be transferred directly to such a
>   `main()` by throwing an exception that
>   is caught in `main()`.
>
> [209]: Any C streams associated with
>   `cin`, `cout`, etc (27.3) are flushed
>   and closed when static objects are
>   destroyed in the previous phase. The
>   function `tmpfile()` is declared in
>   `<cstdio>`.

---

On a related note, `std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` is disturbingly misleading.